# Android Process Stats: app only appears in the foreground

Tags: android, memory, background, ram, foreground

I'm new in Android development. I built an app to access a web server to retrieve some data from the DB. Now I want to analyze the memory usage. To do that, I'm using Process Stats on Android 5.1, but my app only appears in the foreground, with no records of background usage. Why is that?

I don't have any services running on background, but I think it should display the memory usage when the user is not interacting with the app.

It's probably a dumb question, but I'm confused by this.

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor the data through Device Monitor tool (read more: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monitor.html).

Android Studio gives you tools to do that, read the "Memory Monitor Walkthrough" article: https://developer.android.com/tools/performance/memory-monitor/index.html.

Comment: Android Studio, from what I understood, gives the logical memory used by the app. I want a physical measure of the memory usage.